# Search input on focus and change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, search, input

I'm working on a search form which I like to work like the search form on IOS (i.e. App Store)
On focus the input field stretches.
If no text was inserted into the input field, it return to its original state. 
If text was insterted, it remains in its stretched status.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thank you very much!

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i> 
<input type="text" class="form-control-filter input-filter-sm" placeholder="Search">
```

CSS

```
.input-filter {
      width: calc (100% - 25px); 
      width: -webkit-calc(100% - 25px); 
      width: -moz-calc(100% - 25px); 
 }
.input-filter-sm {
      width: 75px; 
}
```

JQUERY

```
$( ".mobile-filter input" ).focusin(function(){
  $( ".mobile-filter input" ).addClass("input-filter");
  $( ".mobile-filter input" ).removeClass("input-filter-sm");
});

$( ".mobile-filter input" ).focusout(function(){
  $( ".mobile-filter input" ).removeClass("input-filter");
  $( ".mobile-filter input" ).addClass("input-filter-sm");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things I have changed in your code, I changed the selector and added the class to your input field. it's working now.

```
$( "input.mobile-filter" ).focus(function(){
  $( "input.mobile-filter" ).addClass("input-filter")
  $( "input.mobile-filter" ).removeClass("input-filter-sm")
});

$( "input.mobile-filter" ).blur(function(){
   var textLen = $(this).val().length;
  if(textLen === 0) {
    $( "input.mobile-filter" ).removeClass("input-filter")
    $( "input.mobile-filter" ).addClass("input-filter-sm")
  }
});
```

Your HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i> <input type="text" class="form-control-filter input-filter-sm mobile-filter" placeholder="Search">
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/mqb6jdhz/)

Comment: @kurious-ser, your welcome, also you can use jQuery animate method to apply some cool effects.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

HTML

```
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
```

Javascript
        var inputSearch = document.getElementById('search');

```
    inputSearch.onfocus = function() {
      inputSearch.style.width = '75px';
    }

    inputSearch.onblur = function() {
      if(!inputSearch.value) {
        inputSearch.style.width = '100%';
      }
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nup177nd/10/